# In Mysql, how to fill a column with incremental integers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database named "planning" in which a column named "planning_id" is badly formatted, indeed it's only filled with 0s.

I would like to fill it incrementally with proper IDs; like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

[image]

I have think about a sql formula like this one:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; 
WHILE (i <= 68) DO
    UPDATE planning set planning_id = i;
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END;
```

But it creates an error (I translate from french to english):

> Unrecognized keywords. Near DECLARE.

Any idea ?

Comment: `INSERT` is for creating new rows, not updating existing rows.

Comment: Is there a primary key or other unique set of columns in the table? You can use a cursor to loop over the rows, and update them based on that unique key.

Comment: Of course I will change this, but do you know how to know by advance the number of rows (here 15)  ?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planning` will tell you how many rows.

Comment: What is the logic/order for the `planning_id` column?

Comment: If you don't mind the sorting of your columns you can `DROP` the `planning_id` and add it again now as Primary Key and with Auto-Increment like : `ALTER TABLE `planning`   
  DROP COLUMN `planning_id`, 
  ADD COLUMN `planning_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`planning_id`);`.

Comment: If you're _"not sure it will work"_ you test your idea on some data you create for the purpose. This is basic debugging that you do first. Only when your code doesn't work **and** you're unable to see how to fix it do you consider posting a question on [so]. Asking a bunch of random strangers on the Internet what they _think_ is not the way to produce reliable code.

Comment: @TheCoolCat thanks, could you make an answer with this solution, I am not sure I totally understand

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the "logic" is that each row should be assigned a different integer. And each integer created should be incremented by one from the previous one (starting from 1). In short, just a simple column with "autoincremented" IDs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the sorting of your columns you can `DROP` the `planning_id` and add it again now as **Primary Key** and with `auto_increment` like :

```
ALTER TABLE planning DROP COLUMN planning_id, 
ADD COLUMN planning_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (planning_id);
```

This way your `planning_id` will refresh their values in an incremental order (1, 2, 3, 4 and so on).

**Check [MySQL AUTO INCREMENT Field](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_autoincrement.asp)**

> Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically when a new record is inserted into a table.

> Often this is the primary key field that we would like to be created automatically every time a new record is inserted

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = start_value;
```

use auto increment which is the attribute to use when you want MySQL to assign a sequence of numbers automatically to a field (in essence, creating an autonumber field).

Comment: Interesting, but how do I make sure that these autoincrement values will be affected to the planning_id column ?

Comment: ALTER TABLE planning MODIFY COLUMN planning_id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY